How can I make fts4 work with my CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statement?
Using Anaconda 3 and Python 3.10.14 I'm trying to create a table:
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE aaa USING fts4(one, two);

I get:

no such module: fts4

How can I make fts4 work with my CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statement? conda install sqlite-fts4 worked. import sqlite_fts4 worked but was no help. I need to hook fts4 into sqlite3.

After more investigation I have fs5 only, not fs3 or fs4.  FS5 is fine for my needs.
